# Объясните пожалуйста ошибку в моей программе приветствия

Tags: java, консоль, io

Я написал следующий код(программу), где Я пытаюсь прочитать с консоли и вывесте прочитанное на консоль.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.Console;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        Console con = System.console();
        name = con.readLine("Введите свое имя: ");
        System.out.println("добро пожаловать, " + name);
    // write your code here
    }
}
```

Десятая строка `name = con.readLine("Введите свое имя: ");` После выполнения дает следующию ошибку:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:10)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Объясните, почему у меня выводит ошибку(1)

Comment: вы б хоть пометили какая строка у вас десятая. Посмотрите этот [пример](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.13.php), может быть сами догадаетесь в чем причина.

Comment: У меня этот пример нормально работает нормально.

Comment: Не понятно в чём проблема, твой пример работает.

Answer (score 0):

Я рекомендую использовать `BufferedReader`, а на разъяснение ошибки Вам уже скинули хорошую ссылку

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Введите свое имя: ");
        String name = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("добро пожаловать, " + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: можно еще использовать `scanner`, но на практике он очень редко используется